# Matchheight extension for Yii2 do not work

Tags: yii2

I am working on thumbnail gallery, which HTML code contains inside PHP foreach loop. But the problem is that thumbnails cards rendered with defferent height. [image]

To prevent it i decided to use this [extension](https://github.com/voskobovich/yii2-match-height-asset)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<?php foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
    if($counter == 0) {echo '<div class="row">';}
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 thumbnail_block">
        <div class="thumbnail"> 
            <div class="caption">
                <h3><?php echo $value['strategy_title']; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $value['strategy_description']; ?></p>
                <p><button class="btn btn-info" type="button">
                    Узнать больше
                </button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php 
    if($counter == 2 || $key === $last_element) {echo '</div>'; $counter = 0;} 
    else {$counter++;}
}
?>
<?php $this->registerJs('$("thumbnail_block").matchHeight();') ?>
</div>
```

But nothing is working. What`s the problem and how can i solve it, or maybe i should try to find another way to make equal thumbnails heights?

Comment: Try to add dot before class name: `<?php $this->registerJs('$(".thumbnail_block").matchHeight();') ?>`

Comment: @rob006 didn`t help

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in browser console?

Comment: @rob006 When page is rendered i didnt get any JS errors, it`s normally working. If I check in developer mode https://imgur.com/trpBZOc

Answer (score 0):

After all i used CSS to make equal cards heights

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) {
    .row.equal-height {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
.row.equal-height > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.row.equal-height.row:after,
.row.equal-height.row:before {
    display: flex;
}

.row.equal-height > [class*='col-'] > .thumbnail,
.row.equal-height > [class*='col-'] > .thumbnail > .caption {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.row.equal-height > [class*='col-'] > .thumbnail > .caption > .flex-text {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.row.equal-height > [class*='col-'] > .thumbnail > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; /* force image's height */

    /* force image fit inside it's "box" */
    -webkit-object-fit: cover;
       -moz-object-fit: cover;
        -ms-object-fit: cover;
         -o-object-fit: cover;
            object-fit: cover;
}
}
```

In my yii build i use CDN to load styles, because of that site was always in the cache of browser. After i deleted cache everything started work. Now if i want to reload the whole site i press Shift+F5